# What software for test script versioning

Tags: test-management

What are some good and reliable software tools for versioning and housing test automation and manual scripts?

Comment: Give us some use-cases what do you need to version exactly? For test scripts you can use git or and source code version control system.

Comment: need  to version automation and manual scripts that are used to run test cases.  I will look into git. thanks

Comment: Do you have a version control system that your dev team uses? It's often simplest to use the same tool across dev and test, especially for automated test scripts.

Comment: I use and recommend Bitbucket, especially for small distributed teams.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the list of some most populer version control tools.

> - SVN
> - CVS
> - GIT (prefer)
> - Mercurial
> - Bazaar

I will suggest GIT because it is a fast and efficient system, many system administrators and open-source project use GIT, However, it is not as easy to learn as SVN or CVS, so beginners may need to steer clear if they’re not willing to invest time to learn the tool, after under understanding you may use **SourceTree** tool which is easy to use for GIT user.

Answer (score 0):

subversion is easier to comprehend for beginners than git, but use whatever your developers and sysadmins use